# Should we migrate posts from the blog to be self-answered questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, blog

I think, unfortunately, that without active attention, the site blog (http://blog.photo.stackexchange.com) has failed. There is a lot of great content, though. I propose that we convert the existing articles to self-answered questions. (And leave room for more answers on each topic; why not?) Some of them might even make great answers to existing questions.

I think most of the article authors are still active on the site. When enough are moved, we could ask Stack Exchange to automatically redirect from the blog to the site,  maybe even article by article, if they are willing to do that.

Note: as of late 2016, [Stack Exchange staff has indicated that the blog platform will be shutting down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285478/blogoverflow-text-overflow#comment925838_285478), so we should do this sooner rather than later.

Comment: This is a great idea. You have full Community Team support for this endeavor (though there isn't much we can actually help you with).

Answer (score 5):

I went through the posts from the last couple months the blog was active (September and August 2012.) I think the **tl;dr takeway** is that this would work pretty well, with the main consequence being more visibility for these great articles and more site reputation for the authors.

### [Pseudo-Macro Photography with a Telephoto Lens](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/pseudo-macro-photography-with-a-telephoto-lens/)

Written by active user (and site moderator) jrista, and would easily translate to "**Can I take macro photographs with a regular telephoto lens?**"

I've created [What techniques can I use to take "macro" photographs with a regular telephoto lens and no adapter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86272/what-techniques-can-i-use-to-take-macro-photographs-with-a-regular-telephoto-l) — if @jrista doesn't show up to answer soon I will provide his blog post as a community wiki post.

### [6 Tips for Wedding Second-Shooters](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/6-tips-for-wedding-second-shooters/)

Written by active user ElendilTheTall. Part of the idea of the blog was to be a place to put list-of-tips questions that often turn out poorly on the Q&A site. However, those can really be okay when they get decently-comprehensive and thoughtful long answers, which this basically is. I think this would make a great answer to [What is a second shooter supposed to do at a wedding?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/what-is-a-second-shooter-supposed-to-do-at-a-wedding)

### [5 Street Photography Tips](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/5-street-photography-tips/)

Another nice "tips" article by ElendilTheTall. I think this could basically be the answer to something like "**How do I get started with street photography?** I'm interested in this style of shooting, but am a little nervous about getting started.... what do I need to know and what kind of equipment would be good?"

### [Thinking Outside the Box: Telephoto Landscapes](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/thinking-outside-the-box-telephoto-landscapes/)

ElendilTheTall again. This would be an excellent answer to [How can a telephoto lens take great landscape photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21812/how-can-a-telephoto-lens-take-great-landscape-photos)

### [Birding Tips – Boosting Your Kit, Using the Gear & Getting Close](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/birding-tips-boosting-your-kit-using-the-gear-getting-close/)

By jrista. "**How can I get started with birding when I can't afford expensive gear?**", maybe? Or, could answer [Birding on a budget?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40621/birding-on-a-budget)

### [Using Photoshop’s Calculations tool for black and white conversion](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/using-photoshops-calculations-tool-for-black-and-white-conversion/)

By ElendilTheTall. Straightforward howto Q&A: "**How do I use Photoshop’s Calculations tool for black and white conversion?**" and there we are.

### [The G-Series Canon always meant to make](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/the-g-series-canon-always-meant-to-make/)

By active user Itai. This one is a review; I don't know really how it would fit in.

### [Tilt-Shift Lenses for Portrait Photography](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/tilt-shift-lenses-for-portrait-photography/)

By active user dpollitt. Answers [What are the techniques for taking portraits using a tilt shift lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/32411/what-are-the-techniques-for-taking-portraits-using-a-tilt-shift-lens), and in fact dpollitt already quotes his blog post there. Might as well copy the whole thing in.

### [The True Quality of Top-Shelf Glass – A Birder’s Perspective](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/the-true-quality-of-top-shelf-glass-a-birders-perspective/)

By jrista. Maybe "**Are expensive lenses really worth it for bird photography?**"

### [Advanced Lightroom Editing – The Adjustment Brush](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/advanced-lightroom-editing-the-adjustment-brush/)

By jrista. These howto articles I think adapt really easily: "**How do I use Lightroom's Adjustment Brush?**"

### [Panasonic Leica Summilux DG 25mm F1.4: Yeah, it is all that.](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/panasonic-leica-summilux-dg-25mm-f1-4-yeah-it-is-all-that/)

By mattdm. That's me. :) I think this could be something like "**Does the Panasonic Leica Summilux DG 25mm F1.4 live up to its name, price, and reputation?**"

### [A Few Tips for Travel Photography](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/a-few-tips-for-travel-photography/)

By ElendilTheTall. Could possibly answer [How to make travel photography captivating, intriguing, thrilling?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6966/how-to-make-travel-photography-captivating-intriguing-thrilling) or [How do I plan a successful set of travel photographs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33852/how-do-i-plan-a-successful-set-of-travel-photographs)

### [How to photograph fireworks](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/how-to-photograph-fireworks/)

By active site user AndyML. Answers [What settings should I be using to photograph fireworks?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/what-settings-should-i-be-using-to-photograph-fireworks)

Comment: Nice, I missed this meta post. Thanks for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw it out there as a consideration for discussion if people are voting on the idea...

What about getting the blog rolling again? Do we think that's even possible? I'm not strongly in either camp, to be honest, but I wonder if we just need to see if we can drum up some interest in getting it going again. I, for one, would love to see some more content there from some of our more experienced photographers.

Comment: It would just take someone really committed to running it. But if someone is interested, I would really like the blog to be **focused on articles which really don't fit the main site**. That would be interviews, camera reviews, and maybe some list-type posts. As you can see from my answer here, many of the exiting posts would do just fine on the main site, and having them separate just dilutes that.

Comment: @mattdm - Yeah, that's the hard part. I'm terrible at keeping my own personal blog(s) going as it is, so I'm not necessarily a good choice for that.

Comment: Personal experience: I never found the blog posts on my own, only when a link to one was given in a question or answer on main site. Yes, I had seen the link to blogs, but as I'm no fan of blogs elsewhere I didn't suddenly turn interested in blogs here either. My bad, the content here is great.